# failed to open stream: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11

Tags: php, file-get-contents, router

I am using slim php router and for some reason I get this error.

> Warning: file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs/views/users.php?userId=3): failed to open stream: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11

here is my index code.

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/users/{userId}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    if (!ctype_alnum($args['userId'])) {
        $args['userId'] = '0';
    }
    $body = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/views/users.php?userId={$args['userId']}");
    return $response->write($body);
});
$app->run();
?>
```

for testing purposes I put this in the users.php file located in the views folder

```
<?php
echo $_GET['userId'];

?>
```

You can find this php router on https://github.com/slimphp/Slim

Answer (score 2):

In order to execute a PHP script you have to go through the webserver, not access it as a local file. So it should be

```
$body = file_get_contents(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/views/users.php?userId={$args['userId']}");
```

Comment: This did not work dirname(__FILE__) starts at the directory of the file you are user dirname(__FILE__)

Comment: sorry for the late response I fell a sleep

Comment: I know `dirname(__FILE__)` doesn't work. It accesses it as a local file, it doesn't run the script, because that has to go through the webserver.

Comment: dirname(__FILE__) works with file_get_contents as well as dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']). They both work. They both do not work with "/views/users.php?userId={$args['userId']}", I have tested your code and mines and it does not work your answer does not answer my question.

Comment: Please read this carefully http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `file_get_contents` not use the url parameter

```
file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/views/users.php");
```

Comment: Do you have an alternative for passing the userid to the users page so it can show the right user when requesting an id

Comment: sorry for the late response I fell a sleep

Comment: This will just return the PHP source code, it won't run the script.

Comment: It will not show the php source. It shows the html output, when you use a php file in file_get_contents It outputs the html source. For example `index.php` = `<?php echo file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/homepage.php'); ?>` and `homepage.php` = `<?php echo 'Hello!'; ?>`